# Does Jon Snow ever bring his direwolf, Ghost, into battle?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, jon-snow

Robb Stark's direwolf, Grey Wind, accompanies Robb on his campaign against the Lannisters and often fights alongside him in the War of the Five Kings. This implies direwolves are useful in battle.

**Did Jon Snow ever bring his direwolf, Ghost, into battle?**

Jon Snow fought in several battles and skirmishes where Ghost's presence would have been useful.

Please provide answers with quotes from the books, not the TV series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. In his fight with Qhorin Halfhand, the help of Ghost was a deciding factor.

> And then Qhorin's sword was coming at him and somehow Longclaw leapt upward to block. The force of impact almost knocked the bastard blade from Jon's hand, and sent him staggering backward. You must not balk, whatever is asked of you. He shifted to a two-hand grip, quick enough to deliver a stroke of his own, but the big ranger brushed it aside with contemptuous ease. Back and forth they went, black cloaks swirling, the youth's quickness against the savage strength of Qhorin's left-hand cuts. The Halfhand's longsword seemed to be everywhere at once, raining down from one side and then the other, driving him where he would, keeping him off balance. Already he could feel his arms growing numb.
>
> **Even when Ghost's teeth closed savagely around the ranger's calf**, somehow Qhorin kept his feet. But in that instant, as he twisted, the opening was there. Jon planted and pivoted. The ranger was leaning away, and for an instant it seemed that Jon's slash had not touched him. Then a string of red tears appeared across the big man's throat, bright as a ruby necklace, and the blood gushed out of him, and Qhorin Halfhand fell.
> <sub>A Clash of Kings - Jon VIII</sub>

As for any big premeditated battle, not that I know.

- In the battle prior to Qhorin's duel, at the ambush of the frostfangs, Ghost was left behind because the white fur would stand out too much in the dark.

  > Qhorin Halfhand looked at him. Jon could hear the wind keening as it shivered through the high pass above them. One of the garrons whickered and pawed at the thin stony soil of the hollow where they had taken shelter. "The wolf will remain with us," Qhorin said. "White fur is seen too easily by moonlight." He turned to Stonesnake. "When it's done, throw down a burning brand. We'll come when we see it fall."
  > <sub>A Clash of Kings - Jon VI</sub>
- When they were captured by Rattleskirt, Ghost was quickly distracted by the eagle and left the battle:

  > But when they emerged back into the light long hours later, the eagle was waiting for them, perched on a dead tree a hundred feet up the slope. Ghost went bounding up the rocks after it, but the bird flapped its wings and took to the air.
  > <sub>A Clash of Kings - Jon VIII</sub>
- Afterwards comes the climb of the wall, and the subsequent fights at the tower in the lake and the siege of Castle Black. Here, Ghost isn't present, because he is still on the other side of the wall.

Comment: Noice. Also might wanna note re: Robb and Greywind, Robb eventually came to regret ever taking Greywind to battles. The wolf lost all fear of mankind as a result.